# how to create loop to draw number of circles?

Tags: android

Hi guys I want to draw only 3 circles on map in eclipse but with for loop to draw a specific number of circles and I write for loop statement as you see in my code but dose not work

this is my code where can I write the statement of for loop to work very well?
please help
thank you...

```
public class Map extends  Activity implements OnMapClickListener
{

    final int RQS_GooglePlayServices = 1;
    private GoogleMap myMap;

    Circle myCircle;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //TODO Auto-generated method stub
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);


         FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
         MapFragment myMapFragment = (MapFragment)myFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
         myMap = myMapFragment.getMap();
         myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
         myMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
         myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
         myMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {

        int z =3;   

        CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
       .center(point)   //set center
       .radius(500)   //set radius in meters
       .fillColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)  //default
       .strokeColor(Color.BLUE)
       .strokeWidth(5);

        for(int circle = 0 ; z > circle ; z--){
            myCircle = myMap.addCircle(circleOptions);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean `...my code but dose not work`?

Comment: I mean in my code below

Comment: What about your code isn't working? Is it not doing what you want it to do or is it throwing errors all over the place? Is it just the for loop that isn't working the way you want it to? What is it doing instead? The more relevant details you give, the more likely you are to receive help.

Comment: code is working very well to draw one circle for each click on map but I want to limit drawing by drawing one circle for each click till I reach 3 circles

Answer (score 0):

Why not use

```
for(int circle = 0; circle < z; circle++)
```

for your for-loop?

Comment: it is same but another way but my question is where can I use it either this for(int circle = 0; circle < z; circle++) or for(int circle = 0 ; z > circle ; z--)